# how to add output stream relationship result of executestreamcommand processor into original flow file in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I need a help. I am using python script here. I wanted to add output stream relationship result of ExecuteStreamCommand processor into original flow file in nifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html

check `Output Destination Attribute` property - if it's empty then all what you print/write to STDOUT will go to flow file content

in python you could write to stdout using simple print:

```python
print("hello world") # this will go to file content
```

or sys module:

```python
import sys

sys.stdout.write( "Hello Standard Output!\n" )
```

to append flowfile content - you have to copy from stdin to stdout current file content and then write something new

```python
import sys
#write current file content (use buffer for binary mode - python3+
for chunk in iter(lambda: sys.stdin.buffer.read(4096), b''):
  sys.stdout.buffer.write(chunk)

sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
#append new data
sys.stdout.write('new data at the end...')
```

Comment: Hi @daggett, How can i use this STDOUT? I tried with it but still not getting desired output. Can you just show me the example?

Comment: i have added examples.

Comment: Hi @daggett, yes but it's generating two files, "original file" and "output stream file" but I want the output of the script as "output stream file" should be appended with "original file"

Comment: added changes..

Comment: It's working as expected.Thanks a lot.